# Prove $NOTCONTEXTFREE_{TM}$ is not recursively enumerable?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language, context-free-grammar, turing-machines

$NOTCONTEXTFREE_{TM}$ = {$\langle M \rangle$, M is a turing machine and the language of M is not context-free}.

I'm trying to prove the language $NOTCONTEXTFREE_{TM}$ is not recursively enumerable. I've tried reducing it from $\overline A_{TM}$ but I've been stuck on it for hours.

Comment: Since we don't know what $\overline A_{TM}$ means, it is hard to figure out what you've tried.

Comment: $\overline A_{TM}$ = { <M,w> | M does not accept w}, this is definitely not r.e

Comment: Please don't put clarifications in the comments.  Instead, [edit] the question to incorporate all relevant information into the post itself, and make it so it reads well and is self-contained for someone who encounters the question for the first time.